# How to make the initial landing page is not the login form from spring security?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Currently, I am using spring-security with a custom login page. Whenever I start my app, it always landed on my login page first instead of home in not login state. I want to make my initial landing page to a home HTML in the not login state and show login button.

This is my WebSecurityConfig.java

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }
```

This is the controller that handling the login page and home page

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String home (){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
```

this is my login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>

    <object th:include="fragments/fragment :: css" th:remove="tag"></object>
    <object th:include="fragments/fragment :: js" th:remove="tag"></object>

 </head>

<body>
        <div id="login">
            <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Halo!</h3>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                            <form id="login-form" class="form" th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
                                <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="submit">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #9be3de;
  height: 100vh;
}
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box {
  margin-top: 120px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form {
  padding: 20px;
}
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form #register-link {
  margin-top: -85px;
}
</style>
```

and this is my home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://thymeLeaf.org">
<!-- <html xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"> -->

<head>
    <title> Home </title>

    <object th:include="fragments/fragment :: css" th:remove="tag"></object>
    <object th:include="fragments/fragment :: js" th:remove="tag"></object>
</head>

<body>
    <nav th:replace="fragments/fragment :: navbar"></nav>
    <img style="width: 100% ; background-size: cover;" th:src="@{/img/webconstruction.png}">
</body>
</html>
```

My expectation is that when you first access the site, it will land on my home.html with not login state and show a login button instead of my login.html. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow anonymousAccess to your home page by configuring pattern `"/"` with `permitAll`

**Note:** If login success defult success URL will be `"/"`(context root). You need to **override success url**, otherwise after login it will again redirects to home page.
Just for an example if your post login screen is dashboard then configure success url to dashboard as given in below code.

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll() // This will be your home screen URL
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/postloginscreen") //configure screen after login success
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }
```